# check if at least one radio button is selected from inputs with the same class javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a small quiz web app using javascript/html. The individual questions on the page are separated by div tags with the same "quiz" class. There are 2 buttons on the page, a previous and a next button. Depending on what the user clicks, the page will display the next quiz on the page by hiding/showing the divs. What I am trying to do is add an input validation to the application. Before the user moves onto the next question I want to make it so that one radio button must be selected, otherwise show an alert box. The radio buttons that belong to the same question all have the same class (i.e. the radio buttons for question 1 all have the same class quiz1). Currently app is able to check which input has been selected (by using if element.checked). Following this logic, I tried using if(!element.checked) create an alert, however the alert box get stuck in a loop. Thus, so far the only other solution I have been able to come up with is to check if at least one radio button within the same class has been selected, which I am unsure how to achieve.

```js
let savedAns = [];
const nextBtn = document.getElementById('next');
const prevBtn = document.getElementById('prev');
const quizes = document.querySelectorAll('.quiz');
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const inputEl = document.querySelectorAll('input');
const total = quizes.length;

//a variable to increment the classes
let ind = 0;

//get all the input elements for each question, assign a class
quizes.forEach(function(element) {
  ind++;
  let inputs = element.querySelectorAll('input');
  inputs.forEach((input) => {
    input.classList.add(`quiz${ind}`)
  })
})

//keep a track of which question is visible 
let count = 0;

//function to hide all the quizes
const hide = function() {
  quizes.forEach((element) => {
    element.style.display = 'none'
  })
}
//show and hide divs when user presses next
nextBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (count < total - 1) {
    inputEl.forEach(function(element) {
      if (element.checked) {
        savedAns[count] = element.value;
        console.log(savedAns)
      }
    })
    count++;
  } else {
    inputEl.forEach(function(element) {
      if (element.checked) {
        savedAns[count] = element.value;
        console.log(savedAns)
      }
    })
    alert('no more questions left')
    return
  }
  hide();
  quizes[count].style.display = 'block'
})

prevBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (count > 0) {
    count--;
  } else {
    alert('no more previous questions')
    return
  }
  hide();
  quizes[count].style.display = 'block'
})
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <form>
    <div class="quiz">
      <p>Question 1</p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="1">
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="2">
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="3">
    </div>

    <div class="quiz" style="display: none;">
      <p>Question 2</p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="1">
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="2">
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="3">
    </div>

    <div class="quiz" style="display: none;">
      <p>Question 3</p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="1">
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="2">
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="3">
    </div>

    <div class="quiz" style="display: none;">
      <p>Question 4</p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="1">
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="2">
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="3">
    </div>
  </form>
  <button id="prev">Prev</button>
  <button id="next">Next</button>
</div>
```

If there are any other ways to solve the problem, hints towards the right direction is greatly appreciated. I am also writing this application using purely javascript so no jquery please. Thank you.

Comment: change name of Question 2,3,4.
for eg.

<div class="quiz" style="display: none;">
      <p>Question 2</p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer2" value="1">
      <input type="radio" name="answer2" value="2">
      <input type="radio" name="answer2" value="3">
    </div>

Comment: @RaviAshara thank you for your comment. I was wondering if you could please explain the reason behind changing the name instead of the class? Thank you.

Comment: in your example there are 3 options in each answer so you can set names of each questions.

so you have to check for each questions answer.

Comment: only the three radio buttons related to a specific question should share the same name. There can be only one active option with the same name. So when you select (i.e.) option2 of the second question you loose the selected option on question1. And this is the issue in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already know which question is active currently, you can check if any of the input under the active question is checked.

```
let selectedAnswer = -1;
  const activeInputs = quizes[count].querySelectorAll('input');
  activeInputs.forEach((input, index) => {
    if(input.checked) selectedAnswer = index;
  });
  if (selectedAnswer === -1) {
    alert('Select answer');
    return;
  }
```

below is the working code snippet.

```js
let savedAns = [];
const nextBtn = document.getElementById('next');
const prevBtn = document.getElementById('prev');
const quizes = document.querySelectorAll('.quiz');
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const inputEl = document.querySelectorAll('input');
const total = quizes.length;

//a variable to increment the classes
let ind = 0;

//get all the input elements for each question, assign a class
quizes.forEach(function(element) {
  ind++;
  let inputs = element.querySelectorAll('input');
  inputs.forEach((input) => {
    input.classList.add(`quiz${ind}`)
  })
})

//keep a track of which question is visible 
let count = 0;

//function to hide all the quizes
const hide = function() {
  quizes.forEach((element) => {
    element.style.display = 'none'
  })
}
//show and hide divs when user presses next
nextBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  let selectedAnswer = -1;
  const activeInputs = quizes[count].querySelectorAll('input');
  activeInputs.forEach((input, index) => {
    if(input.checked) selectedAnswer = index;
  });
  if (selectedAnswer === -1) {
    alert('Select answer');
    return;
  }

  if (count < total - 1) {
    inputEl.forEach(function(element) {
      if (element.checked) {
        savedAns[count] = element.value;
        console.log(savedAns)
      }
    })
    count++;
  } else {
    inputEl.forEach(function(element) {
      if (element.checked) {
        savedAns[count] = element.value;
        console.log(savedAns)
      }
    })
    alert('no more questions left')
    return
  }
  hide();
  quizes[count].style.display = 'block'
})

prevBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (count > 0) {
    count--;
  } else {
    alert('no more previous questions')
    return
  }
  hide();
  quizes[count].style.display = 'block'
})
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <form>
    <div class="quiz">
      <p>Question 1</p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="1">
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="2">
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="3">
    </div>

    <div class="quiz" style="display: none;">
      <p>Question 2</p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="1">
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="2">
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="3">
    </div>

    <div class="quiz" style="display: none;">
      <p>Question 3</p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="1">
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="2">
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="3">
    </div>

    <div class="quiz" style="display: none;">
      <p>Question 4</p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="1">
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="2">
      <input type="radio" name="answer" value="3">
    </div>
  </form>
  <button id="prev">Prev</button>
  <button id="next">Next</button>
</div>
```